# Chart Js , repeated labels yAxis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Y have this issue:
User 1 repeats twice in two colors, gray and white.
Gray should not be seen
[image]

This problem starts when I put styles to the x axis, it repeats the labels.
is there any solution for this case?
The requirement is simply to change the color of the axis labels and ticks.
The gray bar is at the bottom, that is, it does not stack with the red and blue ones

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["User1", "User2"],
  datasets: [
      {
      stack:1,
      label: "TotalTime",
      backgroundColor: "red",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [50, 50],
      yAxisID:1
    },
    {
      stack:1,
      label: "TotalTime",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [40, 40],
      yAxisID:1
    },
    {
      label: "Leave",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(191,191,191, 0.5)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [100, 100],
      yAxisID:1
    },
  ],
};

var options = {
  indexAxis: "y",
  scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          color: "white",
          font: {
            size: 12, 
          },
        },
        stacked: true,
      },
      x: {
        ticks: {
          color: "white",
          font: {
            size: 12, 
          },
        },
      }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```css
canvas{
  background-color:black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.6.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of your `yAxisID`, you dont define it but chart.js still makes a new axis for it since it isnt made by you with that id, so if you remove that or make it `y` which you have defined it doesnt make it again anymore

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["User1", "User2"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "TotalTime",
      backgroundColor: "red",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [50, 50],
    },
    {
      label: "TotalTime",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [40, 40],
    },
    {
      label: "Leave",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(191,191,191, 0.5)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [100, 100],
    },
  ],
};

var options = {
  indexAxis: "y",
  scales: {
    y: {
      ticks: {
        color: "white",
        font: {
          size: 12,
        },
      },
      stacked: true,
    },
    x: {
      stacked: true,
      ticks: {
        color: "white",
        font: {
          size: 12,
        },
      },
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.6.2/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: The gray bar is in the background, that is, it does not stack with the red and blue ones.